# Error while Invocating IOS Driver with Desired Capabilities: "IOSEelement cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: automated-testing, java

Hi there I have the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AutomationName;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class Base {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        DesiredCapabilities d = new DesiredCapabilities();
        d.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPHONE 6");
        d.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "IOS");
        //
        d.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.IOS_XCUI_TEST);
        d.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "//users//xcodeclub//Desktop//UICatalog.app");
        IOSDriver<IOSEelement> driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),d);

    }

}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    IOSEelement cannot be resolved to a type
    Cannot infer type arguments for IOSDriver<>
    '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

    at Base.main(Base.java:29)
```

I have tried some marvens but is not working, someones know how to help me? I am new in the automation thing and I do not know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you cast the driver correctly and import all necessary libraries. Here is the example on [Appium's GitHub](https://github.com/appium/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/java/junit/src/test/java/com/saucelabs/appium/UICatalogTest.java)

```
...
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement;
...
AppiumDriver<IOSElement> driver;
...
driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```